# Mean value theorem to prove local extremum of a polynomial function

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I work on an assignment in which I have to prove the following with the mean value theorem:

Let $$p(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kx^k $$ be a polynomial with $\deg(p(x))\geq2$ which has $n$ diverse roots. 
Then every point in which $p(x)$ has it's local extremum lies between the biggest and the smallest root of this polynomial.

Frankly, I have no idea how to tackle this one.

Comment: Try to use the fact that local extrema are roots of $p'$, and that a root of $p'$ is between two roots of $p$ (using, e.g., the MVT or Rolle's Theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between any two distinct roots, $p'$ has a root. If there are $n$ distinct roots of $p$, this gives us $n-1$ distinct roots of $p'$. As $\deg p'=n-1(>0)$ there are no roots of $p'$ besides these. But any local extremum  of $p$ not lying between the biggest and the smallest root would lead to another root of $p'$ ..

Answer (score 0):

This is a corollary from Rolle's theorem. The idea is, for every two consecutive roots of $P(x)$, $x_1$ and $x_2$, such that $x_1<x_2$, there has been a point where $P'(x)=0$ for some $x \in ]x_1,x_2[$. Also, we know $d^{\circ}P'(x) = d^{\circ}P(x)+1$. Thus, every local extreme value is in between the smallest and largest roots of $P(x)$.